# Schedule execution of mediaplayer in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-mediaplayer

I'm new to Android development and I need some help with a little problem.
I have a background Service that runs my media player and communicate with my PlayerActivity.
So far so good.

I need to schedule the execution of the tracks in different periods. i.e Play track x for one minute than play track y for 30 seconds etc.

So I call MyTimer thread form the PlayerActivity, this thread throws event at the specific time,
the PlayerActivity catches the Event and calls the MediaplayerService next() method.
My Problem is if I call next() without the thread it works fine, If i call it with the thread I get

```
 mContext is null, can't getMirrorDisplayStatus!!!
```

with mediaplayer warning (1, 902)
I've tried to run this thread with from the PlayerActivity via Handler.post() and runOnUiThread()
and I get the same error.

below is the code for MyTimer Thread.

```
public class MyTimer implements Runnable {


private Object mPauseLock;
private boolean mPaused;
private boolean mFinished;
private TimeSection section;


public Trainer()
{
    mPauseLock = new Object();
    mPaused = false;
    mFinished = false;
    BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
}



@Override
public void run()
{
    while (!mFinished)
    {
        TimerManager tm = TimerManager.getInstace();
        this.section = tm.getCurrentTimeSection();
        if(this.section == null)
            mFinished = true;
        else
        {
            tm.inc();
            // produce sectionChangeEvent event
            BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceSectionEvent());
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep((this.section.getTypeDuration() * 1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        synchronized (mPauseLock)
        {
            while (mPaused)
            {
                try
                {
                    mPauseLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

  /**
 * Call this on pause.
 */
public void onPause() {
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Call this on resume.
 */
public void onResume() {
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = false;
        mPauseLock.notifyAll();
    }
}

@Produce public TimeSectionEvent produceSectionEvent(){
    return new TimeSectionEvent(this.section);
}



}
```

some code of the Player Activity:

```
public class PlayerActivity implements
    IMediaPlayerServiceClient{

private MediaPlayerService mService;

....

/**
 * Binds to the instance of MediaPlayerService. If no instance of
 * MediaPlayerService exists, it first starts a new instance of the service.
 */
public void bindToService()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);

    if (MediaPlayerServiceRunning())
    {
        // Bind to LocalService
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } else
    {
        startService(intent);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


    }

}

.....

/*
* This is how I start the timing thread
*/
private void startTiming()
{
    mTimer = new MyTimer();
    runOnUiThread(mTimer);
//  trainingHandler.post(mTrainer);
}

public void next(TimeSection section)
{
    mService.next(section);
}

/*
* Here I catch the TimeSectionEvent from MyTimer thread
*/
@Subscribe public void onSectionChanged(TimeSectionEvent e)
{
    TimeSection section = e.getSection();
    if(section != null)
         next(section);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

each activity has context so from the exception that you got i guess its a problem with the context of the MediaPlayerService.

you are using bindService(...) to bind the intent to the MediaPlayerService that should bind the context.

try to check if that binding is still there when you are trying to do "mService.next(section);"

Comment: I checked for it and it's still bound... :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem SOLVED!

The problem was that I was that the timing thread was running on the UI thread -> calling `Thread.sleep` made the UI thread sleeping as well.
So I end up using `IntentService` that doing the timer thread job in background.

```
public class TimingService extends IntentService{

private Object mPauseLock;
private boolean mPaused;
private boolean mFinished;
private TimeSection section;

public TimingService()
{
    super("TimingService");
    mPauseLock = new Object();
    mPaused = false;
    mFinished = false;
    BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{

    while (!mFinished)
{
    TimerManager tm = TimerManager.getInstace();
    this.section = tm.getCurrentTimeSection();
    if(this.section == null)
        mFinished = true;
    else
    {
        tm.inc();
        // produce sectionChangeEvent event
        BusProvider.getInstance().post(produceSectionEvent());
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep((this.section.getTypeDuration() * 1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    synchronized (mPauseLock)
    {
        while (mPaused)
        {
            try
            {
                mPauseLock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}

}
  /**
 * Call this on pause.
 */
public void onPause() {
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Call this on resume.
 */
public void onResume() {
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = false;
        mPauseLock.notifyAll();
    }
}

@Produce public TimeSectionEvent produceSectionEvent(){
return new TimeSectionEvent(this.section);
}

@Subscribe
public void onPauseEvent(PauseEvent e)
{
    this.onPause();
}

@Subscribe
public void onResumeEvent(ResumeEvent e)
{
    this.onResume();
}
}
```